# Unable to update CloudFormation stack after SSM parameter is recreated

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam-cli

In AWS SAM, I have a stack A, with creates an AWS Systems Manager (SSM) Parameters. Stack B references that stack with: `{{resolve:ssm:<param name>}}`. After a deployed stack A and B (with `sam deploy`, I dropped stack A (fact: nothing prevented this) and recreated it. The value of the SSM param was not changed. A few days later, I tried to deploy a new version of stack B. The operation failed with this message:

```
Status reason: Parameters: [ssm:/<my parameter name here>:1:1649319972738] last modified date does not match with the last modified date of the retrieved parameters.
```

I understand what happened: my stack B refers to a param version 1 with a last modified date older than the last modified date of the newly deployed version 1 of the parameter in stack A. The problem is, I am no longer able to update stack B.

I had no other option than to drop stack B and redeploy it completely (which is unacceptable). Any ideas how to prevent this?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4800344)

Comment: Can you create a new/temp param with the same value, then update stack to use the temp param, then update it again back to the new version of the real param?

Comment: Impossible, any change using SAM-CLI fails.